# PHP function only run if not accessed directly

Tags: javascript, php, function

Currently, I run a PHP function only if `GET` requests are sent to the file that it is included in. I send these requests to the PHP file through JavaScript. Also, I want it to ONLY run the function if the get requests are sent through the JavaScript file and is not accessed directly.

For instance:

`run.js`

```
function runfun(what, data) {
    $.get("files/functions.php",{
                       run:'true', 
                       what:what, 
                       data:data
            }, 
            function(data) {
            }
    }
```

`functions.php`

```
if (isset($_GET['run']) && isset($_GET['what']) && isset($_GET['data'])) {
    runstuff($_GET['what'], $_GET['data']); // I do NOT want this to run if
                   // the functions.php file is accessed directly and if the GET 
                   // variables are set on the page itself
}
```

Comment: Add a unique token to the request which expires after a certain time. You could also check if the request is from AJAX, but it can be spoofed.

Comment: Submit with POST and you'd take away most "regular" users from being able to call it "directly" without a REST client.

Comment: You should be able to check `REQUEST_URI` and/or `SCRIPT_FILENAME` in the [`$_SERVER` array](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is really a bulletproof way of accomplishing this, however, you could use something like the following to detect AJAX requests:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* special ajax here */
    die($content);
}
```

Please note this could be spoofed.

Code taken from: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Additionally, as @FDL pointed out in their comment, you could use a nonce.